# Jmeter : How to Add data file for use in request body variable?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am a new Jmeter.
I would like to add sample data for use in request body.

For Postman, I can add data file and it will retrieve value to assign in request body variable. but for Jmeter,  How can I add data file (json file)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOgyA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEdkU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IO54.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function. It reads the file from the given path and returns its content in the place where the function is placed/called.

[image]

It's also possible to save the value into a JMeter Variable for later re-use. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

If you have folder with multiple files and would like to send the different one on each iteration of each virtual user - you can combine it with [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md)